# Django sub-query in Case When

Tags: django

I have such query

```
qty_used_annotation = Case(
        When(scope='ticket', then=BookedTicket.objects.filter(
                global_discount_code__code=F('code'), booking__status__in=['i', 'c', 'g', 'r', 's']
            ).count()),
        When(scope='booking', then=Booking.objects.filter(
                bookedticket__global_discount_code__code=F('code'),
                status__in=['i', 'c', 'g', 'r', 's']
            ).count()),
        output_field=IntegerField()
    )
```

And it is not working. The error is **Cannot resolve keyword 'code' into field.**
Can somebody explain how to fix it or why it is not working.
Thanks

Comment: Please share your models. Likely there is a more effective way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In subqueries you need to use [`OuterRef`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.OuterRef) instead of `F` to access field from outer query:

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery, Count

qty_used_annotation = Case(
        When(scope='ticket', then=Subquery(BookedTicket.objects.filter(
                global_discount_code__code=OuterRef('code'), booking__status__in=['i', 'c', 'g', 'r', 's']
            ).annotate(count=Count('id')).values('count'))),
        When(scope='booking', then=Subquery(Booking.objects.filter(
                bookedticket__global_discount_code__code=OuterRef('code'),
                status__in=['i', 'c', 'g', 'r', 's']
            ).annotate(count=Count('id')).values('count'))),
        output_field=IntegerField()
    )
```

Comment: When doing with OuterRef get error: This queryset contains a reference to an outer query and may only be used in a subquery.

Comment: Try to wrap it in `Subquery` method and return count as `.annotate(count=Count('id')).values('count')` not `count().

Comment: OK. It working, but I also need to remove duplicate Booking objects, how can I do this?

Comment: Not sure, but try to pass `distinct=True` argument to `Count` method: `count=Count('id', distinct=True)`

Comment: Found error when subquery returns more then 1 row: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression. Could you help?

Comment: Subqueries in django should always return one row. Check this doc: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/expressions/#limiting-the-subquery-to-a-single-row So in your case the only you could do is to add `[:1]` slicing for subquery: `annotate(count=Count('id')).values('count')[:1]`

Comment: Ah, so how could I count number of bookings then, any other way to it?

Comment: I suppose current approach works fine. Because for each row in booking query we add total count number. Each row contains correct and exactly the same count. So it doesn't matter if we return only the first row.

Comment: But of course this is only my opinion) It's better for you to double check this.